# Equivalent of dynamic query params for React Native Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to dynamically show profiles based on userId in React Native. In react where I set up my routes, I'd add something like `route="/users/:userId"`, and then use that userId to make various calls, display various data, etc. When I implement a link to the profile page, I route them to, say, `/users/1`.

How can I achieve something similar in React Native? The only thing seen around the web is to pass it in as params, but does that mean I've got to pass it in each time I call `navigation.navigate`? I'm not sure what the route-defining or the `navigation.navigate` syntax should look like.

I've checked [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885554/react-native-navigation-params-drawernavigator) of [SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985837/react-native-tabnavigator-navigation-params), but none of them seem to answer this fundamental question. And all of the docs and [articles](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introducing-react-navigation-5/) about dynamic routing in React Navigation seem to mostly concern passing in dynamic title headers and stuff.

Comment: Yes, you pass the `userId` in the second argument when you call `navigation.navigate`.  On the user route, you use the route props to access it.  It will write a more complete answer.

Comment: "Passing Parameters to Routes": https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Navigation primarily uses a params object which looks like `{ userId: 1 }` rather than a string-based route definition like `"/users/:userId"`.

#### Linking to a Profile

The [`navigation.navigate` function](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#navigate) takes two props: the `name` of the route and the `params` to pass.  You don't need to include the second `params` argument at all if you are navigating to a route which doesn't take any parameters.  `navigation.navigate("Home")` is fine. But when going to your "User" route you will **always** need to include a `userId`.

In order to go to a particular user profile, you would call:

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("User", { userId: 1 })}
```

Docs: [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

#### Accessing Params

That `userId` param can then be accessed in the `UserScreen` component through the props which are injected by the navigator.  Every screen receives props [`route`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop) and [`navigate`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop).  The `params` are a property of the `route` prop.

So you can define a `UserRoute` component like this, where we get the current `userId` from `route.params.userId`.

```
const UserScreen = ({route, navigation}) => (
  <View>
    <Text>Viewing profile for user #{route.params.userId}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
      <Text>Back to Home</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

(Typescript users: this component is `React.FC<StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "User">>` where `RootStackParamList` is your own app's param definitions)

#### Declaring Routes

You don't actually *need* to say anything about the params when you create your routing.  This works just fine:

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

There are some additional optional configurations that you can use.  You can [map the params to options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen#options) or [map the params to a unique screen id](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid), for example.

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="User"
  component={UserScreen}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    title: `User Profile #${route.params.userId}`
  })}
  getId={({ params }) => params.userId.toString()}
/>
```

(Typescript users will want to define a type, typically called `RootStackParamList`, which maps each route to its params types.  This is then used as the generic on `StackScreenProps`, `StackNavigationProp`, etc.)

#### String-Based Navigation

React Navigation *does* support linking to paths like `"/user/1"`, but it requires additional configuration.  Behind the scenes it still uses a params object, so you need to [define a mapping](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links#passing-params) from the path to the params.  It can be a custom mapping, or you can use the same syntax that React Router does with `:` to define params.  `"users/:userId"` will create a params object with the `userId` as the key.

Your `Stack.Screen` component stay the same.  The configuration options are passed as a prop `linking` to the `NavigationContainer` component.  If you set this up then you are able to use the experimental [`Link` component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/link) like you would in React Router to link to a path like `"/users/1"`.

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={{
        prefixes: ["https://yourdomain.com"],
        config: {
          screens: {
            Home: "",
            User: "users/:userId"
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-params-in-react-navigation-zrjr4?file=/src/App.tsx) with typescript types.